# reverse array function doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I want to reverse an array without using the built-in methods but the following function is not working:

```
function reverseArray(arr) {
  let brandNewArray = [];

  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    brandNewArray += arr[i];
  }

  return brandNewArray;
}


reverseArray([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function instead of `+=`.

```js
function reverseArray(arr) {
  let brandNewArray = [];
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    brandNewArray.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return brandNewArray;
}

console.log(reverseArray([1,2,3]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `+=` you need to push items into it. Using `+=` at first time will assign to the `brandNewArray` a string, (as `[] + 1` will give you `"1"`), with value of the last item. Then string concatenation goes and you got `321` as the final value of `brandNewArray` instead of array.

```js
function reverseArray(arr) {
  let brandNewArray = [];
  
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     brandNewArray.push(arr[i]);
  }
  
  return brandNewArray;
}


console.log(reverseArray([1,2,3]))
```

### Also you can use more compact version of your code

```js
const reverseArray = arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc.unshift(cur), acc), []);

console.log(reverseArray([1,2,3]))
```